# comparing different signals

Tags: signal-analysis, noise

I have some noise measurements and 4 different models that can generate a similar noises using estimated parameters from the real measurements. To compare the estimated noises I calculated the PDF, the CCDF and the PSD.

To compare the results I used the Kull-Back Leibler divergence of the PDF, the MSE of the CCDF and the RMSE and the corr2 matlab function for the PSD.

I am not sure if I did the right thing.

Can you please tell me if what I did is correct and do you know any other way or function to make such comparison?

Thanks.

Comment: it might be useful to expand each TLA (three letter acronym) when it's first used.  i dunno what a *"CCDF"* or *"RMSE"* is, although i can guess that *"DF"* is *"density function"* and *"MSE"* is *"mean square error"*.

Comment: maybe I was a little bit fast, my mistake! Here is the expand of the acronyms:

CCDF is Complimentary cumulative Density function

PDF is Probability density function

PSD is Power spectral density

MMSE  minimum mean squared error

RMSE  Root mean squared error.